# How to set Spring Active Profiles Pragmatically from a configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

On a project I'm working on we have some old dependencies that define their own spring beans but need to be initialized from the main application. These beans are all constructed using spring profiles, i.e. "default" for production code and "test" for test code. We want to move away from using spring profiles, instead simply using @import to explicitly wire up our context.

The idea is to encapsulate all these old dependencies so that no other components need to care about spring profiles. Thus, from a test`s point of view, the application context setup can be described as follows:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyTest { 
  //tests
}
```

TestContext further directs to two classes, one of which encapsulates the old dependencies:

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = {OldComponents.class, NewComponents.class})
public class TestContext {
  //common spring context
}
```

To encapsulate the old components` need for profiles, the OldComponents.class looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = {OldContext1.class, OldContext2.class})
public class OldComponents {

  static {
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "test");
  }

}
```

The problem here is that the static block does not appear to be executed in time. When running mvn clean install, the test gets an IllegalStateException because the ApplicationContext could not be loaded. I have verified that the static block gets executed, but it would appear that OldContext1 and OldContext2 (which are profile dependent) are already loaded at this time, which means it is too late.

The frustrating thing is that IntelliJ runs the tests just fine this way. Maven, however, does not. Is there a way to force these profiles while keeping it encapsulated? I've tried creating an intermediary context class, but it didn't solve the problem.

If we use the annotation @ActiveProfiles on the test class, it runs just fine but this kind of defeats the purpose. Naturally, we want to achieve the same in production and this means that if we cannot encapsulate the need for profiles, it needs to be configured in the web.xml.

Comment: Is a web application? if yes you can set the environment in web.xml

Comment: Yes it is a web application. What we`re trying to accomplish is not having to set it in the web.xml though, instead we want to encapsulate the profiling to the specific context classes.

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration classes inherits of AbstractApplicationContext you can call:

```
getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("your_profile");
```

For example:

```
public class TestContext extends AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext {

      public TestContext () {
            getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("test");
            refresh();
      }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. It would appear that maven insists on completely loading and evaluating the contexts prior to java code execution.

Answer (score 0):

It definietly seems that `OldContext1` and `OldContext2` are being class-loaded and initialized before the static block in `OldComponents` is executed.

Whilst I can't explain why there is a difference between your IDE and Maven (to do so would require some in-depth knowledge of some, if not all all, of : spring 3.x context initialization, maven surefire plugin, SpringJunit4ClassRunner and the internal IntelliJ test runner), can I recommend to try this?

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = {UseTestProfile.class, OldContext1.class, OldContext2.class})
public class OldComponents {
    // moved the System.setProperty call to UseTestProfile.class
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class UseTestProfile {
    static {
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "test");
    }
}
```

If I am understanding your problem correctly, class `UseTestProfile` should be loaded first (you might want to investigate a way to guarantee this?) and the other two classes in the import list should have the system setting they need to initialize properly.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This was suggested by a colleague a few hours ago. Unfortunately, it didn`t work. His line of reasoning was exactly like yours.

Comment: Sounds like you have some smart colleagues ;) What didn't work? Was the ordering of class loading of the imports non-consistent?

Comment: All I know is that it didn´t work. I`m unsure about why specifically maven chooses to do what it does, but it`s evident that it loads and evaluates everything before executing any java code. In this case, it`s a pity. I had to timebox the project so unless something comes up here on SO, it`s unlikely that I will be able to find a solution.

Comment: Use @Profile in the configuration class, where you can specify the profile for each context

Answer (score 0):

You need make sure, environment takes effect at first.This is how I do:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledIni {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void inilizetion() {
        String mechineName = env.getProperty("MACHINE_NAME");
        if ("test".equals(mechineName) || "production".equals(mechineName) {
            System.setProperty("spring.profiles.default", "Scheduled");
            System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "Scheduled");
        }
    }
}
```

In scheduler add annotation `Prodile` and `DependsOn` to make it work.

```
@DependsOn("scheduledIni")
@Profile(value = { "Scheduled" })
@Component
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @profile annotation in the class to load the configuration like below

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class UseTestProfile {
}
```

and set the value for the property `spring.profiles.active` either in property file or as a runtime argument